# Starting a thread with a paramenter

Tags: java

I would like to start a thread and pass in an object which I create somewhere but want to set its values from within the thread.

How is this achieved?

Thanks

Comment: You can find more examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877096/java-threading-pass-parameter-to-a-thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass it when you construct the `Thread` (or preferably, [`Runnable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)):

```
public class Task implements Runnable {
    private YourObject yourObject;

    public Task(YourObject yourObject) {
        this.yourObject = yourObject;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        yourObject.setSomething("something"); // See?
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I was trying to add it to the run method. :/