# How to pass an argument to a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, arguments

Assume I would like to pass the following variable

```
String foo = "hello world";
```

as an argument to the following thread

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // SOME CODE HERE REQUIRES VARIABLE
    }
}).start();
```

Can someone please explain how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877096/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-java-thread

Comment: @TheGoodGiant in the linked question Thread is subclassed while here it is not. Also here there is a simpler solution available...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local variables that are declared as *`final`* will be visible in the thread:

```
void doSomething(final String foo) {
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // SOME CODE HERE REQUIRES VARIABLE
        System.out.println(foo);
      }
  }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Subclass Thread:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

   private String arg;

   public MyThread(String arg) {
      this.arg = arg;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
        // Use your variable
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Can someone please explain how to do this.

So your problem has more solutions but nicely from the beginning. I suggest you to create own subclass of `Thread` and pass parameter via its **constructor**.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    public MyThread(String value) {

    }
}
```

Or you can also use `Runnable` interface as well.

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable { ... }
```

### Update:

Or like @erickson pointed out you can wrap your code into body of method but as method's argument you have to pass final variable because you cannot cannot refer to a non-final variable inside inner class defined in a different method.

Comment: -1 No need to belittle questioner.  It's a reasonable question.

Comment: @jordan002 belittle? are you kidding me? i wrote three possible approaches he can use. I mentioned subclass because if he will want to change this variable since is declared as final this is not possible. Only define next helping variable. sorry but i disagree with you.

Comment: If he does want to change the value of the variable from another thread, there are many pitfalls.

Comment: @erickson i know :) it's not trivial.

Comment: @Sajmon Judging from your reaction I'm guessing you get this kind of feedback a lot.  If the question was obvious, there'd be no reason to ask.  Not to mention the fact that a linked question has (right now) about 42 upvotes.  Seems a pretty good question to me.

Comment: @jordan002 no man, i was very surprised only from your feedback, it was first time, this kind of reaction and now i know what you hate, its words i used, truly sorry, i fix it.

Comment: @jordan002 i updated answer, now everything is ok? :)

Comment: @Sajmon Looks good. Your answer is spot on, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass argument using anonymous classes in Java. What you can do is create a separate class and pass it as instance variable

Answer (score 0):

```
String foo = "hello world";
final String parameter = foo;
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
         //Use parameter
    }
}).start();
```