# Get constructor's parameter as a method's variable

Tags: java

```
class Param implements Runnable {
int c;

public Param(int a, int b){
    c = a+b;
}

public void run(){
    // System.out.println(a); // <<<<----What I'm going to do. it's impossible. 
}

 }

public class ParamTest {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Runnable r = new ThreadParam(10,20);
    new Thread(r).start();  

}   
}
```

In above code, How can I print the value of "a"? My goal is, when I call  `Runnable r = new ThreadParam(10,20)` in main method, I want to print value of "a" --> `10` . Is this impossible? If I declare `int a` into run() method, the result of "a" is '0'. I want to the result "10". How can I do that?

Comment: Change your design and add an instance variable that stores the value of `a`.

Comment: Possible duplicate:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20640896/passing-parameters-to-java-thread

Comment: @RahulTripathi That was my question. But I stucked another problem : this question. Please consider it, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another instance variable to hold the `a` value:

```
int a;
```

and in your constructor, copy it down:

```
this.a = a;
```

Then you can access it in another method.

Comment: Where is proper position of `int a`? I want to print value of "a" not 0, but 10. is this impossible?

Comment: Declare it next to your other instance variable, `c`.

Answer (score 3):

Local variables and parameters only exist inside the function that declared them.
You need to store it in a field in the class, just like you stored `c`.

Comment: Declare `int a` into class? or method? then its result is 0. How can I print 10?

Comment: @user3100921: You need to declare it in the class, then assign it in the constructor.  `int a` in the class and `int a` in the constructor are two different and unrelated variables.