# Thread output wrong

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to print out each thread's number aka `1,2,3..`. regardless of the order of the number outputed, but when I ran the code below, many numbers were repeated in the output

```
public static int ThreadNumber = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {

        new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("Thread number : " +  ThreadNumber);
        }).start();

        ThreadNumber++;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Thread number : 3
Thread number : 3
Thread number : 4
Thread number : 5
Thread number : 6
Thread number : 9
Thread number : 9
Thread number : 9
Thread number : 9
```

How can I fix this so each thread outputs a specific number only

Comment: You need a thread lock if you want to share a static variable between the threads, or just print the value of `i` in the threads.

Comment: So for each loop you create a new thread.  Threads take time to spin up, so, it's possible you will have n number of threads who run at some point in the future.  If you want the thread to print just a single number then you should either pass the number to the thread directly or just a semaphore to stop the thread until a new number is available.  I can't really see the point of using multiple threads for this, as a single thread would do the job for you

Comment: How would you pass it to the thread directly? @MadProgrammer

Comment: @George via a constructor, so you'd need to use a custom `Runnable`

Comment: @George  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877096/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-java-thread

Comment: I need it to run multiple separate threads; hence, why it's like that in the code snippet I posted

Comment: @George The linked question should work for your case. Just wrap your code inside a custom Runnable like the answers in that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid mutable global state ("statics").

To pass a value to a lambda expression, assign it to an *effectively final* local variable. No need to escalate to a whole class, yet.

```
int threadNumber = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
    int thisThread = threadNumber;
    new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("Thread number : " +  thisThread);
    }).start();

    ++threadNumber; // Just i in this case.
}
```

Obviously there's no guarantee which order this will print out in - that's the point of threads.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works the way I wanted it to, but I don't understand why making the variable static makes it not work

Answer (score 1):

`ThreadNumber` is shared mutable data. So, you need synchronization to ensure only one thread accesses that shared mutable data.

```
public class Main {

    public static int ThreadNumber = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object lock = new Object();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    System.out.println("Thread number : " + ++ThreadNumber);
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```